# Is the rule "One Remote Player Per Session" Fair/Reasonable?

Tags: gm-techniques, remote

As a DM, I am not very fond of having some players "remote in" through my laptop/webcam, but due to everyone's busy schedule, I've recently made a rule to allow one person per session, first person to call it gets it.

Is this fair and reasonable to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Whether something is *fair* or *reasonable* isn't usually something the site can answer objectively. Fair or reasonable for one group isn't always fair and reasonable for another. However, this is a good topic for a discussion site like one of these in [this link](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610). If you were to rephrase this question with *a lot* more information (group composition, layout of the playspace, game system, and maybe even the limits of your electronics—to start!) the site may be able to handle it. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Indeed... I have some strong, experienced-based opinions on mixing remote and local play... but the question doesn't really ask for that.

Comment: @T.J.L. Your experiences would probably be valuable to the site. Consider asking and also answering a question like *What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a mixed group of local and remote players?* or something similar. Perhaps even the user who asked this question would find such information valuable!

Comment: @HeyICanChan I just might... but I figured I'd give a new user a chance to do so and earn some rep first.

Comment: @Paul See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!